# SELinux prevented httpd(usr/sbin/httpd) write access to /var/www/html/bookings/templates_c

Tags: linux, smarty, fedora, apache, selinux

I am using a framework which uses `Smarty` template engine. It works fine in Windows, but when I tried to run it in LAMP server, I got a message like `SELinux has detected suspicious behaviour on your system`. The whole error message i have attached. Please guide me what to do. Thanks[image]

Comment: I just disable the selinux whenever it comes in my way !! "set enforce 0"

Comment: Thanks Ashish..I to disabled SELinux ! `setenforce 0` and its done

Comment: That is of course a bad idea if you have general access to your system and there are people out there that would like to break into your system. If your machine is inside a firewall with no external access, and it's not got anything valuable on it, then feel free to use this. The correct solution is to configure SElinux to do allow the things you want, but not everything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can allow it by using `setsebool -P httpd_unified=1`

Normal SELinux settings for http to work with PHP more or less properly are:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi on
setsebool -P httpd_unified on
setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting on
```

Otherwise you can use

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

To get a list of httpd-related EeLinux options and tweak to your personal taste.

Comment: `httpd_unified` is not necessary in most--if not all--cases.  Take a look at [dan walsh's blog: security vs. usability](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/62262.html?thread=343350)

Comment: i don't know this thing, but `setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi on` did the trick