# Laravel Socialite Facebook can't get user details

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am following the following tutorial 

 http://tutsnare.com/social-authentication-in-laravel-5/ 
I have followed the steps exactly as said, but when I try to dump my user object which I retrieved using the following code:

```
$user = Socialize::with('github')->user();
dd($user);
```

This is not giving any output. However

```
$user = Socialize::with('github');
dd($user);
```

Does return the following object:

```
GithubProvider {#194 ▼
  #scopes: array:1 [▶]
  #request: Request {#37 ▶}
  #clientId: "a client id here"
  #clientSecret: "a client secret here"
  #scopeSeparator: ","
  #encodingType: 1
  #stateless: false
  +"redirectUrl": "My redirect URL
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set up my server, the machine generated an SE Linux Error, saying that httpd service tried to save in logs of laravel. 
I noticed this error later and stackoverflowed the error, finding the following solution. 
[SELinux prevented httpd(usr/sbin/httpd) write access to /var/www/html/bookings/templates_c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069453/selinux-prevented-httpdusr-sbin-httpd-write-access-to-var-www-html-bookings-t)

Did as said in the question and voila! Done!